# AWS Fargate with API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-fargate

I am following this(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/access-private-applications-on-aws-fargate-using-amazon-api-gateway-privatelink/) tutorial to create API Gateway and Fargate. This is the architecture I want to follow. I like to have my container in private subnet and I want to expose the API through API Gateway.

I am able to follow the tutorial and everything works perfectly. This tutorial is using public NGINX image.
Now I tried to replace the Nginx image with my own docker image built with golang and stored in AWS ECR private repository. With docker image from my private repo, I get below error.
**{"message": "Internal server error"}**

I have not been able to figure out this error. I feel like I am missing some security configuration. But I can't figure out. Any help is really appreciated.

Go Code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func helloResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello world"))
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(helloResponse))
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", mux)
}
```

I am able to run docker image locally successfully.

Comment: Does your ECS service work, without NLB? Can you query your API from your VPC from some instance?

Comment: Thank you for your response Marcin. I am new to AWS. Based on what I learned NLB is necessary to access resources in private subnet. I have not tried to access the API with an instance within the vac.

Comment: So first step to troubleshoot your problem would be to confirm that your ecs service is actually working. Since its private, you can try accessing it from an ec2 instance.

Comment: If you're using a VPC link and a private DNS name then you'll need to verify your DNS. I ran into this issue and it returned cryptic 500 errors until I figured it out. Here's the AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/endpoint-services-dns-validation.html